# Are the Azure Client Id, Tenant, and Key Vault URI considered secrets?

Tags: wpf, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, endpoint

I'm getting up to speed with Azure and trying to follow best practices for securing my WPF and Xamarin.Forms apps.

I'm using Azure AD for authentication and Key Vault for my secrets.

What about my Client Id and Tenant settings?  These are required to make the initial connection to Azure to log in.

The endpoint URI is also required to make a call to the Key Vault.

Are the Client Id, Tenant, Key Vault endpoint considered secrets or am I over thinking this.  I understand without authenticating, no one can access or make use of these.

What about checking these into Source Control?  Is this Ok?

Greatly appreciate your thoughts and insights.

Karl

Answer (score 8):

**TenantId** is hardly a secret. You can get the tenant metadata of any Azure AD tenant using the following Url

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID/domain}/.well-known/openid-configuration

For example
https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

**ClientId** also travels in http Urls and thus is not that hard to find out. That's why the focus should be to effectively protect access to the app using either [token validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens) or [user assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal).

[Managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) is available to help avoid checking in any credentials in source control and is specially useful with KeyVault.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into Managed Identities.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I could not get Managed Identities to work.

I think my problem is that my application logs into AD using the scope "user.read"  to read the Graph.  This works fine.

Then, I access an Azure Function but the Bearer token does not have the correct scopes added and the request is denied.

I've tried adding additional scopes to my login, but can't figure out how to configure my Portal correctly to access my Functions, I'm getting this error.

Part One...

Comment: Part Two...

AADSTS65005: The application 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' asked for scope 'api.read' that doesn't exist. Contact the app vendor.


Is there an end-to-end walk-through to add an Azure Function, configure the scope for the function in the Portal?

I just want to have an Azure Function that uses AD Auth.  I think the mismatch of scopes on the server and what I'm passing in WithExtraScopesToConsent is my problem.

Thank you.