# Azure AD / MSAL.js - is it safe to include the tenantId?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it safe to include the `clientId` and `tenantId` in the `msal.js` implementation?  I believe i read Joonas Westlin say that embedding the ClientId is fine (I can't find the post now).

There is a place for it in the library so it seems that it is ok:

```
this.msal = new UserAgentApplication(
                {
                    auth: {
                        clientId: this.clientId,
                        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${this.tenantId}`,
                        redirectUri: Uri + "/login",
                    },
```

However one would think such identifying information is to be kept secret.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**, it's safe to include `clientId` and `tenantId`.

Your concern is valid since with JavaScript based applications (like SPA's) any information that you're putting in is potentially exposed to users and can be misused. Although `tenantId` and `clientId` aren't such information, `client secret` or `keys` would be something sensitive and to be avoided.

`tenantId` is available publicly anyway as part of the OpenID Discovery document for tenant. You can access it using a URL of this format

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID or tenantDomain}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

`clientId` is an identifier for your app registration. To answer your concern about including it.. `clientId` alone doesn't establish application's identity, you need to have `client secret` along with it as well, to be able to use application's identity.

So from a security standpoint any public client application (like a JavaScript based SPA or even a desktop native app) should not make use of client secret, as these applications can not keep it safely and it can get compromised. Secrets can only be handled by confidential clients like server based web application or backend daemon process.

Here is Microsoft guidance for Implicit grant flow which is usually the flow used by JavaScript/SPA apps - [**Microsoft identity platform and Implicit grant flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)

Here is a similar SO post about `clientid` and `tenantId` with good explanation - **[Are the Azure Client Id, Tenant, and Key Vault URI considered secrets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016004/are-the-azure-client-id-tenant-and-key-vault-uri-considered-secrets/56016091#56016091)**

I couldn't quickly find the post from Joonas Westlin that you mention in question, but Joonas's advice about `clientId` is correct as usual.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit. You seem to have lots of activity related to Azure and Azure AD.

Comment: @HankCa you’re welcome! Yup working closely with them right now :)

Comment: Cool.  Did you see my other AAD question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698377/passport-azure-ad-msal-js-and-dynamic-scopes ? :)

Comment: Add to that that msal.js can't store auth state in http-only cookie and this is by design!
Also here's Joonas's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614117/532675