# passport-azure-ad / msal.js and Dynamic Scopes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Azure AD v2.0 discusses one of their advantages as being Dynamic Consent (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/api-scopes#request-dynamic-scopes-for-incremental-consent).

What is this supposed to look like?  I thought a typical use case would be to supply what roles / scopes apply to a certain end point.  For example the `@OAuthBearer()` annotation on:

```
@Get("/hello-auth")
@OAuthBearer({"scopes": ["app.special.scope"]})
helloAuth() {
    return {text: "Authorised hello"};
}
```

I cannot find any information on how to do this.  It seems to me (looking at the protocol diagram at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#protocol-diagram) that the only activity `passport-azure-ad` takes is to receive a bearer token and verify it.  That makes sense, but then how are the scopes on the annotation assessed since they are server-side and thus not known about by the client to included in the token?

I asked this at https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad/issues/430 but my contract ends next week and I want to finish this off, so cross-posted this.

As in that post, I thought of using the `msal.js` library but can't see how I'd make that work either.

Is there any best approach to this problem?

Comment: I worked out what I'll do.  I'll send a 'preflight' request to get the scopes to pass to `MSAL.js / acquireTokenSilent` method.  That will auth the person against the scope and they'll have a bearer token to pass to the API (with `passport-azure-ad` doing its thing).  I'm yet to implement that.

Comment: But now see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746473/azure-ad-a-scope-is-always-required-but-need-a-default-one.  Aghhhh my frustrations with Azure AD grow and I have not received any responses to any of my posts here on SO or at https://github.com/AzureAD/ (passport-azure-ad or msal) from anyone from Azure.  Disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for the solution, here is what worked for me.

1. Defined strategy options separatly.

```
    const strategyOptions = {
       identityMetadata: MicrosoftCredentials.identityMetadata,
       clientID: env.client_id,
       clientSecret: env.client_secret,
       scope: ["email", "profile", "offline_access"],
       ...
    }
```

2. Create strategy

```
    passport.use(new AzureAd.OIDCStrategy(strategyOptions, verifyCallback));
```

3. Add the scope required for your API call just before calling the `passport.authenticate`. Example:

```
      strategyOptions.scope += " Calendars.ReadBasic";

      return passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {})
```