# Are Azure Application Client ID's safe to store in the frontend?

Tags: javascript, azure, vue.js, security, single-page-application

On the Microsoft website they have multiple examples on how to use `msal` to authenticate users to the Azure AD within an SPA. In all these [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular) the `Application (client) ID` is stored in plain text in the code or in a simple `.json` file.

My question, given that everything stored in the front end is considered to be public, is it bad practice to simply store the app configuration like `Azure (client) ID` in a `json` file? Or would this be better stored in a `.env` file?

These are the details the app would need to function:

```
AZURE_APP_CLIENT_ID=""
AZURE_APP_AUTHORITY=""
AZURE_APP_REDIRECT_URI=""
AZURE_APP_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI=""

API_URI=""
API_AZURE_EXPOSED_SCOPE=""
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the OAuth RFC defines it as not a secret: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.2

> The client identifier is not a secret; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used alone for client authentication.

The client id will be visible in the URL anyway when the user signs in.
Storing it in front-end is totally fine.

All of these things are visible in the URL when the user logs in:

- Azure AD tenant id
- App client id
- Scopes the application is requesting (which can include client ids/app ID URIs of APIs in your AAD)
- App redirect URI

Comment: Thanks for the info. That makes things simple so only a `.json` file will do. Much appreciated.